# Is it possible in istanbul JS coverage report to see which tests are actually responsible for this line to be covered?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, istanbul

Istanbul test coverage report looks like

[image]

From the picture above, it is saying line 4 is covered 25 times (or has been run 25 times), is it possible to know exactly which of my tests are hitting this line?

I'm more interested in lines with 1x in fact (the picture is from Istanbul website)